# Why can't Integer.MAX_VALUE also work in this AP CSA array problem?

Tags: java, arrays

The AP CSA problem is: Which replacement(s) for /* some value */ will always result in correct execution of findMin?

```
// arr is the array to be processed 
public static int findMin (int[] arr)
{
    int min = /* some value */;
    int index = 0;
    while (index < arr.length)
    { 
        if (arr[index] < min)
        {
            min = arr[index];
        }
        index++;
    }
    return min;
}
```

The answer choices are:
**I.** `Integer.MAX_VALUE`
**II.** `Integer.MIN_VALUE`
**III.** `arr[0]`

The correct answer is **II and III**, but I want to know why `Integer.MAX_VALUE` would not also work?
The if statement would just run right away & `min` would just be changed a lot more.

Comment: MIN_VALUE is wrong since it is less than any vaalue in arr except for MIN_VALUE.

Comment: Something's off here. Assigning arr[0] to min in findMin will throw an exception if an empty array is passed to findMin. So it could hardly be considered true to say findMin will always return the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

choice II is clearly wrong because the function will always return `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, whatever the content of the input array.

I and III are both possible, but they will differ in the way they deal with an empty input array:

I will return `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

III will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

I prefer the latter.